# Where could these files be coming from?

Tags: file-management

I have a directory on a laptop (a MacBook Pro, in case this is relevant) in which I just discovered a bunch of garbage files that I did not knowingly or manually put there.  They appear to be duplicates of all the other files in the directory, with weird names, like these examples:

`.BC.T_03m1Tf
.BC.T_0E4TU2
.BC.T_2TRggX
.BC.T_37qD4l
.BC.T_3J38mh
.BC.T_3Uve81
.BC.T_3We1Qm
.BC.T_3n4qxQ`

There are exactly 197 of these files, and there are exactly 197 other files that do not follow this naming pattern, and the one that I first discovered has a similar or identical file in the normal files, so I'm guessing that all of them are created as duplicates by some (really annoying!) program.

Where do files with this naming pattern come from?  (Searching has turned up nothing.)

Manually deleting them is not a solution, as I need to know if there's a legitimate reason for them to be there (I doubt it!) and whether anything will break if I delete them, and where else they might be.

Comment: The naming is probably randomized. You could move them to another location, and put them back if they cause any problems. What directory are the files in? What programs are running on your computer? How big are the files? What are the dates? What are the contents of the files?

Comment: Part of the names are either a hash or else random, but I'd guess a hash. The files are in a subdirectory of my home directory, in which I keep files that are sourced by my `~/.zshrc` file.  The contents (as mentioned) appear to be the same as another file in the directory that I *did* put there.  ***The dates are all the same, October 13 at 09:02.***  (That suggests they were all created at once, by the same event.)

Comment: I wouldn't assume they are hashed values. A program could have made those as temporary files using [mktemp()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+5.7&arch=default&format=html). You can reproduce the file names by running `mktemp .BC.T_XXXXXX`

Comment: What kind of files are the other 197?

Comment: Based on your description, they sound like the type of backup files that might be created by a text editor. For example, Vim saves a copy of the file which ends in `~`, Microsoft Word creates a file which *starts* with `~` (and some other characters that I don't remember offhand), and other editors do other stuff.

Comment: @BenN: they're plain text files containing functions and aliases that get sourced into my `~/.zshrc` file.